# Having trouble with SSBO in JOGL

Tags: java, jogl, compute-shader, shader-storage-buffer, buffer-objects

I've been trying to initialize an SSBO and pass it to a a compute shader.

```
int ssbo = glGenBuffers();

FloatBuffer buff = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
buff.put(0.1f);
buff.put(0.4f);
buff.put(1.5f);
buff.put(0.2f);

glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, buff, GL_DYNAMIC_READ);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);

int block_index = glGetProgramResourceIndex(programID, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, "shader_data");
System.out.println(block_index);

int ssbo_binding_point_index = 1;
glShaderStorageBlockBinding(programID, block_index, ssbo_binding_point_index);


int binding_point_index = 1;
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, binding_point_index, ssbo);
```

and in the shader I have:

```
layout(binding = 1) buffer shader_data {
    vec4 sph;
};
```

When I run this, sph is filled with 0-s. 
I tried to read the data from the buffer:

```
FloatBuffer a = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, a);
System.out.println(glGetError());

//and then print a...
```

And this gets me Error 1281, aka 0 + a.size() > the size of the ssbo.
Then I checked the actual size of the SSBO:

```
IntBuffer b = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, b);
System.out.println("buffer size: " + b.get(0));
```

And this gives me 0.
I've used [this](https://www.geeks3d.com/20140704/tutorial-introduction-to-opengl-4-3-shader-storage-buffers-objects-ssbo-demo/) article.
I'm pretty new to OpenGL so there might be a really obvious mistake in my code and that's why I included so much of it here.

Thanks in advice!

Edit: LWJGL version is 3.2.1 build 12

Comment: Just flipping the buffer after filling it with data works.

Comment: Is your problem solved? BufferUtils doesn't come from JOGL 2.

Comment: yes. how do I mark it as solved?

Comment: Answer your own question and wait for two days to be allowed to accept your own answer.

Comment: Please can you at least indicate the version of JOGL you use so that the other developers who see your code understand that it's not really up-to-date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just flipping the buffer after filling it with data works.